# What is difference between epoch and MAX_ITER in FsDet?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am a newbie with this context and I appreciate if someone can help me to understand .

In Fsdet it has a concept [MAX_ITER](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/211efad5f0c23d20e9e52f3ffe29e2975541bd34/detectron2/engine/defaults.py#L484) , however, I am not sure if this term is equivalent to [epoch](https://machinelearningmastery.com/difference-between-a-batch-and-an-epoch/#:%7E:text=at%20an%20epoch.-,What%20Is%20an%20Epoch%3F,update%20the%20internal%20model%20parameters.) . If not , what is the difference between the two terms ?

Thanks,
Yu

Comment: please let me if in anyway I can improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

As you already know epoch refers to a complete pass on the dataset. However, detectron uses mini batch for training, meaning, depending on your batchsize and number of samples in the dataset number of steps (iternations) get determined.

In other words each iteration is training on a single batch, so  epoch is max_iter * batch_size / number_of_samples.

One thing not to confuse iter is STEP parameter on SOLVER.
The fact is STEP refers to the iteration where LR would decay, so there can be multiple single points where we decay LR.